# Recommended way of replacing an application's repository assembly

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have an application that contains a repository assembly.  When the application is initially installed, the repository is very simple: a local JSON file store.  But I want to give my end-users the ability to use a different repository store (SQL, Oracle, etc).

Would it be as simple as replacing the original repository DLL in the application's directory with the new repository DLL? If so, would the user simply copy and paste the new repository DLL into the application's directory, overwriting the original DLL? Is there a better way of doing this?

Note that I also have another assembly in the application which contains all of the interfaces used by the application (is this a good practice?).  The application would verify that the repository assembly implements all of the required interfaces.

I believe that I do not want a plug-in architecture/framework.  I don't want the ability to choose one from a set of loaded repository assemblies.  But I'll listen to any argument favoring a plug-in strategy for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to this matter and from the question I am not sure which one is more suitable for your needs.

1. If you only need to select a behavior among several implementations located in DLLs that can be loaded when the application start, you can reference these statically. At startup, you can browse the AppDomain for loaded assemblies (check AppDomain.GetAssemblies() method) and classes in the assembly and build a Dictionary of available behaviors.This Dictionary can later be used to switch between behaviors.
2. If you really need to have the user handle DLL files at runtime, check AppDomain.Load() methods.These allow dynamically loading of a new assembly in the current AppDomain. Classes in these assemblies can be cast to corresponding common interfaces to be actually invoked. However, note that loading an assembly is easy but unloading one (if you need to do so) is NOT.
3. So if you need to load AND unload assemblies dynamically, these need to be handled within a different AppDomain (check AppDomain.Unload() method). Moreover, method calls between AppDomains cannot be done directly, these need marshaling which adds to the code complexity.

This is a brief summary of these solutions, there are articles detailing each one of them...

Comment: Thanks, avat.  I am assuming that the user is part of a larger organization and that the type of repository (SQL, Oracle, etc.) is dictated by the organization.  So, the repository DLL would only be selected once, probably when the program was installed or shortly after, not every time the user used the program.So, the situation is most similar to your first scenario, but the selection would only occur once.